# Facing Issue with CGAffineTransform in NIB

Tags: ios, xib, swift4.2

I have 2 Views (`viewLeft`, `viewRight`). I am rotating these views with angel 0 (initial setup) by calculating the same anchor point so that it looks like views are rotating across hinge.

I have done below code, which is working fine if I took the views in storyboard (viewcontroller) and it does not work if I copy and paste same views and code in nib. In Nib, at 0 angel views leaves some space between them. It is weird behavior, I checked all code outlets and constraints, everything is fine but unable to figure out why it is not working.

I want it to be working in NIB.

Any help will be appreciable.

**Github** dummy project reference [here](https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/CGAffineTest/tree/master)

### **Outputs :**

**From Storyboard**

[image]

**From XIB**

[image]

### Code work

**Set Anchor point**

```
extension UIView {
    func setAnchorPoint(_ point: CGPoint) {
        var newPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * point.x, y: bounds.size.height * point.y)
        var oldPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * layer.anchorPoint.x, y: bounds.size.height * layer.anchorPoint.y);

        newPoint = newPoint.applying(transform)
        oldPoint = oldPoint.applying(transform)

        var position = layer.position

        position.x -= oldPoint.x
        position.x += newPoint.x

        position.y -= oldPoint.y
        position.y += newPoint.y

        layer.position = position
        layer.anchorPoint = point
    }
}
```

**Rotation function**

```
func rotateView(_ addAngel : CGFloat) {

    let rotateToAngel = angel + addAngel

    guard rotateToAngel <= 0.6 && rotateToAngel >= -0.6  else {
        return
    }
    angel = rotateToAngel
    let anchorPointLeft = CGPoint(x: (viewLeft.frame.width - viewLeft.frame.height/2)/viewLeft.frame.width,
                                  y: ( viewLeft.frame.height/2)/viewLeft.frame.height)

    viewLeft.setAnchorPoint(anchorPointLeft)

    let anchorPointRight = CGPoint(x: (viewRight.frame.height/2/viewRight.frame.width),
                                   y: ( viewRight.frame.height/2)/viewRight.frame.height)

    viewRight.setAnchorPoint(anchorPointRight)


    self.viewLeft.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: rotateToAngel)
    self.viewRight.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: -rotateToAngel)

}
```

Comment: Does the anchor point calculated correctly when running on NIB?

Comment: Yeah I crossed check many times, in both nib and storyboard code my intermediate variable values are same. I recently added dummy project please check.