# Show view from bottom with options

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib

When I navigate to a certain viewcontroller, I want a view from bottom with options like so...

How can I have such a view...?
[image]

> **EDIT 1**

I have tried to achieve as suggested in the link using a tableview instead of collection view. And this is what I have...

[image]

And dragging down the view gives me this view...

[image]

But I come to the view, I don't want the slide up view to cover the entire length of the view, but it should only be of the same size as given in the 1st screenshot. How can I achieve that..?

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: I haven't tried anything..because I'm confused as to what to try...like whether this is a native ios feature or something custom...

Comment: Its not a feature, you have to create yourself. I had made a [demo](https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/TDStickyController) almost like this. Use it and develop it according to your requirement.

Comment: Something similar https://github.com/applidium/ADOverlayContainer

Comment: I opened the file @dahiya_boy But there was nothing in it except a gif and a readme...so how can I use it...?

Comment: @asd2 Check now, in project, the topmost line is rotating & its incomplete so remove that code.

Comment: ok @dahiya_boy..Thanks. I'm checking..:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dahiya_boy. I have edited the question with some changes..please do have a look..

Comment: @asd2 I already mentioned **the topmost line is rotating & its incomplete so remove that code.** I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624858/facing-issue-with-cgaffinetransform-in-nib) that issue but didn't got any reponse.

Comment: Ok @dahiya_boy I'll remove that code as u suggested. But I wanted to reduce the length of the tableview. When I come to the screen, the tableview covers the entire screen. So to reduce the length I tried reducing the length of the visual effect view in the XIB. By doing that the length was reduced. But when I drag the view down, it goes down completely and becomes no more visible. While it should not have gone down completely and showed some portion of it as in your original working...

Comment: @asd2 I know I made this demo with other prospectus. You need some little modifications and it work fine. Wait I will post an answer with aprx exact changes.

Comment: Sure @dahiya_boy..Thanks..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using same github project that I posted in comment.

### **First remove the garbage : File -> `TDStickyView`**

1. Outlets

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var viewLeft: UIView!
   @IBOutlet weak var viewRight: UIView!
   private var angel : CGFloat = 0
   ```
2. From `func viewSetup`

   ```
   :
   :
   // DELETE THESE 2 LINES AND THESE FUNC TOO.
   self.setCursors()  
   self.rotateView(addAngel: 0)
   ```
3. From `handleGesture`

   ```
   if aNewOrigin.y <= 60 {
       self.rotateView(addAngel: .pi/8)
   }
   else if aNewOrigin.y >= 60 && aNewOrigin.y < self.frame.height - 100 {
       self.rotateView(addAngel: 0)
   }
   else {
       self.rotateView(addAngel: -.pi/8)
   }
   ```

### **Now add constraints for cursorView,**

1. For left cursor

[image]

2. For right cursor

[image]

### **Now project is stable and let's talk about your requirements.**

1. Change size of tableView on init.

In `viewSetup` change

```
//topMostY = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
topMostY = parentVC.view.center.y
// It is the top most Y position of tableview and it can't go above it. Change it according to your requirement.
```

2. Hide the TableView completely.

In `handleGesture` change

```
else if sender.state == .ended {
    self.panGestureColView.isEnabled = false
    if velocity.y > 0 {
        // go down
        // UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        //     self.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.parentFrame.size.height - self.bottomMostY), size: self.frame.size)
        // }

        // Change above commented UIView.animate with below UIView.animate

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.parentFrame.size.height), size: self.frame.size)
        }) { (isFin) in
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }
    else if velocity.y < 0 {
        // go up
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.topMostY), size: self.frame.size)
        }
    }
}
```

---

That's all.

Comment: Thanks @dahiya_boy. It worked! Just a correction..Actually I didn't want the tableview to hide completely but wanted a portion of it to remain visible while going down. For that in the handleGesture method, instead of the new code that u added, it was the commented code that was needed. But thanks again...:)

Comment: @asd2  `visualEffectView` can be dark or light and you can change either from storyboard. I used VisualEffect as it looked good on design but If you don't like `visualEffectView` then remove it and use your view and give background color of your choice.